# Differences between Solid Region vs Polygon Pour

Tags: altium

In altium you can define polygon pouring or solid region. It seems both are doing the same things. What are the differences ?

Comment: Just from the sound, I would say it's who does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solid regions are just that: areas of fill (copper, on routing layers) that exist on the layer. These are useful when you definitely want solid fill (silkscreen, copper under a QFN thermal pad) that *will not* be changed by design rules. This still can trigger DRC violations.

On the other hand, polygon pours are "smart" in comparison. They are dynamic; you must define them and *then* create them. Each time you 'pour' the polygon, it is dynamically generated to satisfy clearance and other design rules, in addition to connecting to nets and pads in different ways. This is generally the best thing to use when you want to pour ground or power, but don't want to worry about specifying each place clearance is needed (almost everywhere). I use these for my 'plane' layers and to give full ground coverage on the top/bottom copper layers.

Comment: As I understand we should just use Polygon, not solid region...as polygon are more flexible, right?

Comment: Not really, you use copper pours when the copper is in some sense functional, like say a PCB copper area used as a heat sink, and copper pours when you want the copper to flow around other tracking and such (Like say a copper ground pour on a routing layer).